# Need help parsing a text file using regex in Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell-3.0

I have a text file representing error codes as follows. I'd like to use it as an exercise in relearning regex (I used to know regex years ago and all the knowledge evaporated). Specs are as follows

I only need data from lines that begin with `"public const int "`. I figured this part out by using get-content, reading each line in a loop, and doing a contains search. If there is a better way I'm all years.

Assume the following line:

```
"        public const int TRANSACTION_E_INVALID_ACCOUNT_STATUS = 141080;  //""Invalid account status""      

        "
```

I need the following three fields:

- TranCodeDesc  = TRANSACTION_E_INVALID_ACCOUNT_STATUS
- TranCode  = 141080
- TranDesc = Invalid account status

If there is a tutorial that explains how to parse a line like this I'm all ears as well.

Thanks,

Nick

```
"        public const int TRANSACTION_E_INVALID_ACCOUNT_STATUS = 141080;  //""Invalid account status""                  "
"        [SuppressMessage( ""xxxx.Naming""  "" """"CA1707:IdentifiersShouldNotContainUnderscores"""" )]""               "
"        [SuppressMessage( ""xxxx.Naming""  "" """"CA1709:IdentifiersShouldBeCasedCorrectly""""""   "" MessageId = """"TRANSACTION"""" )]""         "
"        [SuppressMessage( ""xxxx.Naming""  "" """"CA1709:IdentifiersShouldBeCasedCorrectly""""""   "" MessageId = """"RACE"""" )]""            "
"        [SuppressMessage( ""xxxx.Naming""  "" """"CA1709:IdentifiersShouldBeCasedCorrectly""""""   "" MessageId = """"CONDITION"""" )]""           "
"        public const int TRANSACTION_E_TRANSACTION_RACE_CONDITION = 141081;  //""Same transaction was processed by other thread""                  "
"        [SuppressMessage( ""xxxx.Naming""  "" """"CA1709:IdentifiersShouldBeCasedCorrectly""""""   "" MessageId = """"UNSUPPORTED"""" )]""         "
"        [SuppressMessage( ""xxxx.Naming""  "" """"CA1707:IdentifiersShouldNotContainUnderscores"""" )]""               "
"        [SuppressMessage( ""xxxx.Naming""  "" """"CA1709:IdentifiersShouldBeCasedCorrectly""""""   "" MessageId = """"TRANSACTION"""" )]""         "
"        [SuppressMessage( ""xxxx.Naming""  "" """"CA1709:IdentifiersShouldBeCasedCorrectly""""""   "" MessageId = """"OPERATION"""" )]""           "
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out:

`$line -match 'public const int (?<TranCode>.* ).*= (?<CPReturnCode>\d+).*"(?<TranDesc>.*)"'`

Results in

`$Matches.TranCode = BDK_E_TOKEN_ALREADY_BLACKLISTED 
$Matches.CPReturnCode = 5010
$Matches.TranDesc = The token is already blacklisted.`

The narrative of how I think this expression works:

-TranCode is all characters after "public const int ".

-Skip any number of characters up until "= " (equal sign and a space).

-CPReturnCode then equals any number of digits (\d+).

-Skip any number of characters until the next '"' (double quote)

-TranDesc equals any number of characters until the next '"' (double quote)

Nick

Answer (score 0):

```
(?=.*public const int).*?(\w+)\s*(?==).\s*(\d+).*?"([\w\s]+)
```

Try this. Just grab the captures.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lS5tT3/35